# Matlab - Image Recognition - Detecting number of leaves on a plant

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm relatively new to matlab, and i'm attempting to do some image processing.

By applying:

```
g1= im1(:,:,2);
bw1= im2bw(g1);
se=strel('disk',5);
e1=imerode(bw1,se);
bw1a=bwareaopen(e1,100);
```

Comment: It seems your bw image is not better than rgb image, so you can start from improving it.

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag is for the language Processing and not [tag:image-processing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a basic idea of what you should be doing and here are some resources that could helpful.

http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/11/19/watershed-transform-question-from-tech-support/
http://blog.pedro.si/2014/04/basic-cell-segmentation-in-matlab.html
http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/06/02/cell-segmentation/

[image]

```
greenChannel = rawImage(:,:,2);
binaryImage = im2bw(greenChannel);
removeNoise = bwareaopen(binaryImage,1000);

% apply distance transform to find watershed markers
distanceImage = -bwdist(~removeNoise);
distanceImage(~binaryImage) = -Inf;
distanceImage = imhmin(distanceImage,0.9);

% apply watershed transform to split binary blobs
watershedImage = watershed(distanceImage);

% label each blob with an index
labelImage = bwlabel(watershedImage);
% obtain data on each blob
propsStruct = regionprops(logical(labelImage));
% add some color to the image
watershedImage = label2rgb(watershedImage);

figure
hold on
imshow(rawImage)

for leafIndex = 1:length(propsStruct)
    if propsStruct(leafIndex).Area > 2000
        plot(propsStruct(leafIndex).Centroid(1) , propsStruct(leafIndex).Centroid(2) , 'ko')
    end
end
```